# convert from int to byte

Tags: c#, type-conversion, byte

`System.ArgumentException: Object must be of type Int32.`

in this code:

```
MyBO target = new MyBO() { x1 = 20 };
```

In `MyBO` i have an attribute: `public byte x1 {get; set;}`

What's wrong? I tried with `MyBO target = new MyBO() { x1 = (byte)20 };` but i got the same error.
Please help.

Thanks!

Comment: What language is this? Please add to the tag list too...

Comment: It appears to be C#, given the object initializer and `System.ArgumentException`.

Comment: Are you sure that's where the error is happening? I made a similar class with a similar declaration with no problems.

Comment: That's not an attribute, that's a property.  Post real code that reproduces the error.

Comment: Based on the comments to one of the answers, the code given in the question is not like the code that is causing the error. Until the questioner posts complete information, nothing can be done.

Answer (score 3):

```
MYBO target=new MyBO();
target.x1=Convert.ToByte(20);
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure that error comes from that line? I run this code without problems:

```
class MyBO
{
    public byte x1 { get; set; }   
}

// ...
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    MyBO my1 = new MyBO() {x1 = 20};
    MyBO my2 = new MyBO() {x1 = (byte)20};
    MyBO my3 = new MyBO() {x1 = Convert.ToByte(20)};
}
```

Comment: So post your REAL code, as code above doesn't reproduce your error

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried explicitly casting to a byte?

---

`MyBO target = new MyBO() { x1 = (byte) 20 };`

Comment: OK, then the problem is: if i have a validation rule, like:
[RangeValidator(0, RangeBoundaryType.Inclusive, 20, RangeBoundaryType.Inclusive, Ruleset="validate_x1")]
        public byte x1
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

If i have  MyBO my1 = new MyBO() {x1 = 20}, i got that error. Why?

Comment: So can you tell me why i got that error when using RangeValidator in MyBO class?